# Multiple clicks in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to simulate a message writer via jquery.
For example, on the first click on button 2
I need to get an "a", on the second a "b" and a "c" on the third click.
I'm having difficulties because if I click 3 times it does all of the actions,
it doesn't just print the "c".
Thanks

var letters = [];

```
    $('#2').click(function (e) {
        letters.push('a');
        $('#2').click(function (e) {
            letters.push('b');
            $('#2').click(function (e) {
                letters.push('c');
            })
        })
        $('#mytext').append(letters);
    })
```

OK, so if I click twice on button "#2" I get 3 "a"'s, I need to get just a "b" instead

Comment: Some code will definitely help.

Comment: You are binding event handlers inside event handlers When you click on `#2` the first time, you *add* another event handler. Then when you click a second time, the two bound handlers will be executed and two more will be added. At the third click, you already have four event handlers bound to the element and all of them are executed (and bind four more (if I'm not wrong)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store number of clicks in variable and run function on each click with timer. If timer completes before the next click than it will print the character according to the current number in variable otherwise it will reset the timer. Here's the example code..

```
var counter=0;
var timerId=null;

$(document).click(function(){
    counter++;
    if (timerId != null)
        clearTimeout(timerId);

    // Executes after 500 milisecond .. You can increase the timer value..
    timerId = setTimeout(checkClickCount, 500);

});

function checkClickCount()
{
    switch(counter)
    {
        case 1:
            alert('a');
            break;
        case 2:
            alert('b');
            break;
        case 3:
            alert('c');
            break;
    }
    counter=0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed. I always knew I needed to include a timer and a counter:)